# How do I perform a push segue from an imagePickerController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, segue, ibaction

I've wired up a next button that sits on top of an imageView. My imagepicker sets the returned image to the imageView and I want to segue by pressing the IBAction. However when I press it, it doesn't perform the segue. I can see the button is being pressed, so I cant therefore understand why the segue isn't working. Does anyone know why?

```
@IBAction func nextPage(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showCaptionpage", sender: self)        
}
```

Comment: have you added a `print` statement to check that that code is actually reached?

Answer (score 1):

Just drag imagePickercontroller to new Viewcontroller and select push. if you are using  newer xcode version then  push is deprecated. you can select show.